# Service Bus - Cannot Send if first Host is down

Tags: c#, servicebus

We trying to connect A farm of Service Bus Hosts.

```
        serviceCustomConnection.Endpoints.Add(new Uri("sb://a.local/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace"));
        serviceCustomConnection.Endpoints.Add(new Uri("sb://b.local/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace"));
        serviceCustomConnection.Endpoints.Add(new Uri("sb://c.local/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace"));



        serviceCustomConnection.StsEndpoints.Add(new Uri("https://a.local:9355/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace"));
        serviceCustomConnection.StsEndpoints.Add(new Uri("https://b.local:9355/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace"));
        serviceCustomConnection.StsEndpoints.Add(new Uri("https://c.local:9355/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace"));

        serviceCustomConnection.RuntimePort = 9354;
        serviceCustomConnection.ManagementPort = 9355;

        ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.AutoDetect;

        _factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(serviceCustomConnection.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Factory Created");
        retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<ServiceBusTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(new FixedInterval(10, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)));


        retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() => client = _factory.CreateTopicClient("test"));
        Console.WriteLine("client Created");
        retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() => receiver = _factory.CreateSubscriptionClient("test", "App.test"));
        Console.WriteLine("receiver Created");
```

And then send via

```
            retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() => this.client.Send(msg));
```

When all servers are up it works fine. But when the first node is down and we trying to connect to the service bus we get an exception that the first node is activley refused.

What are we missing?